# Python doit module: How to choose which shell to run task actions?

Tags: doit

I am using python doit module as a GNU make replacement.
Seems that doit is running actions on /bin/sh:

```
pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~$ doit merge_phased
.  phase_dataset:15
/bin/sh: 1: [[: not found
TaskError - taskid:phase_dataset:15
Command error: '[[ ! -d phasing ]] && mkdir phasing' returned 127

########################################
phase_dataset:15 <stdout>:
```

I would like to use /bin/bash. I could not find how to accomplish that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

if its a sh file then you can add this at the top  to run with bash

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

to run with ksh